# Using Burp Spider through proxy

Tags: proxy, web-crawler, http-proxy, tor, burp

I'm using Burp proxy in my Tor browser, and am able to intercept HTTP requests successfuly.

However, when running Spider on any of the viewed URLs, the Spider won't run through the proxy, or at least I have no reason to think that it is.

How can I set up Spider to run via Proxy? Preferably the one Tor is providing.

Answer (score 1):

Tor is a socks proxy so go to your settings in Burp. In latest Burp it should be inter user settings or project settings, outgoing proxy. Socks. Set the socks proxy to be 127.0.0.1 9050.

Comment: I did it and although the actions I make through the "proxy" tab are working just fine, when I trid to spider a site I got the folowing exception: java.net.SocketException: SOCKS server general failure. Any solution ideas?

Comment: The proxy tab is for configuring your browser to send request via burp. Check this tutorial. Good luck I hope you aren't doing anything illegal. http://jerrygamblin.com/2015/12/18/proxying-burpsuite-through-tor/

Comment: This question (not answer) lacks a lot of detail.  I don't see how Tor browser fits in.  But my comment anyway, is Tor browser listens on 127.0.0.1:9150 where as the regular Tor daemon uses 9050.  maybe that explains the SOCKS failure.